# Why do linked servers have a limitation of 10 branches in a CASE expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, linked-server

Why does this `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE column 
        WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
        WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
        ... c -> i
        WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
        WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
    END [col] 
FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table
```

Produce this result?

> Error message: Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
> Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 1 
> Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

Clearly there isn't a nested `CASE` expression here, though there are more than 10 "branches."

Another oddity. This inline table-valued function produces the same error:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyFunction]
(   
     @var varchar(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT CASE column 
            WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
            WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
            ... c -> i
            WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
            WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
        END [col] 
    FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table
)
```

But a similar multi-statement TVF works fine:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyFunction]
(   
    @var varchar(20)
)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
    value varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result
    SELECT CASE column 
            WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
            WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
            ... c -> i
            WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
            WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
        END [col] 
    FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table

RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> *Clearly there isn't a nested `CASE` expression here.*

Not in the query text, no. But the parser always expands `CASE` expressions to the nested form:

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1)
        WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
        WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
        WHEN 'c' THEN '3' 
        WHEN 'd' THEN '4' 
        WHEN 'e' THEN '5' 
        WHEN 'f' THEN '6' 
        WHEN 'g' THEN '7' 
        WHEN 'h' THEN '8' 
        WHEN 'i' THEN '9' 
        WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
        WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
    END
FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product AS p
```

[image: Local query plan]

That query is local (no linked server) and the Compute Scalar defines the following expression:

[image: Nested CASE expression]

This is fine when executed locally, because the *parser* does not see a nested `CASE` statement over 10 levels deep (though it does pass one on to the later stages of local query compilation).

However, with a linked server, the generated text *may* be sent to the remote server for compilation. If that is the case, the *remote parser* sees a nested `CASE` statement more than 10 levels deep and you get error 8180.

> *Another oddity. This inline table-valued function produces the same
>   error*

The in-line function is expanded in-place into the original query text, so it's no surprise the same error results with the linked server.

> *But a similar multi-statement TVF works fine*

Similar, but not the same. The msTVF involves an implicit conversion to `varchar(max)`, which happens to prevent the `CASE` expression being sent to the remote server. Because the `CASE` is evaluated locally, a parser never sees an over-nested `CASE` and there is no error. If you change the table definition from `varchar(max)` to the implicit type of the `CASE` result - `varchar(2)` - the expression is remoted with the msTVF and you will get an error.

Ultimately, the error occurs when an over-nested `CASE` is evaluated by the remote server. If the `CASE` is not evaluated in the Remote Query iterator, no error results. For example, the following includes a `CONVERT` that is not remoted, so no error occurs even though a linked server is used:

```
SELECT CASE CONVERT(varchar(max), SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1))
        WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
        WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
        WHEN 'c' THEN '3' 
        WHEN 'd' THEN '4' 
        WHEN 'e' THEN '5' 
        WHEN 'f' THEN '6' 
        WHEN 'g' THEN '7' 
        WHEN 'h' THEN '8' 
        WHEN 'i' THEN '9' 
        WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
        WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
    END
FROM SQL2K8R2.AdventureWorks.Production.Product AS p
```

[image: CASE not remoted]

Answer (score 6):

My hunch is that the query is getting re-written somewhere along the way to have a slightly different `CASE` structure, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN column = 'a' THEN '1' ELSE CASE WHEN column = 'b' THEN '2' ELSE ...
```

<s>I believe this is a bug in whatever linked server provider you're using (in fact perhaps all of them - I've seen it reported against several). I also believe you shouldn't hold your breath waiting for a fix, either in the functionality or the confusing error message explaining the behavior - this has been reported for a long time, involves linked servers (which haven't had much love since SQL Server 2000), and impacts far fewer people than [this confusing error message](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410), which has yet to be fixed after the same longevity.</s>

As [Paul points out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42850/1186), SQL Server is expanding your `CASE` expression to the nested variety, and the linked server doesn't like it. The error message is confusing, but only because the underlying conversion of the expression is not immediately visible (nor intuitive in any way).

One workaround (other than the function change you added to your question) would be to create a view or stored procedure on the linked server, and reference that, instead of passing the full query through the linked server provider.

Another (assuming your query really is this simplistic, and you just want the numeric coefficient of letters a-z) is to have:

```
SELECT [col] = RTRIM(ASCII([column])-96)
FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table;
```

If you absolutely need this to work as is, I suggest you contact support directly and open a case, though I can't vouch for the results - they may just provide you with workarounds you already have access to on this page.

Answer (score 5):

you can get around this by

```
SELECT COALESCE(
CASE SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1)
    WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
    WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
    WHEN 'c' THEN '3' 
    WHEN 'd' THEN '4' 
    WHEN 'e' THEN '5' 
    WHEN 'f' THEN '6' 
    WHEN 'g' THEN '7' 
    WHEN 'h' THEN '8' 
    WHEN 'i' THEN '9' 
    ELSE NULL
END,
CASE SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1)
    WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
    WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
END)
FROM SQL2K8R2.AdventureWorks.Production.Product AS p
```

Comment: 6 years 1 month later.... Thanks @Nik!

Comment: Answer from ypercube is easier IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround for this problem is to use set based logic, replacing the `CASE` expression with a left join (or outer apply) to a reference table (`ref` in code below), which can be either permanent, temporary or a derived table / CTE. If this is needed in multiple queries and procedures, I'd prefer to have this as permanent table:

```
SELECT ref.result_column AS [col] 
FROM LinkedServer.database.dbo.table AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    ( VALUES ('a',  '1'),
             ('b',  '2'), 
             ('c',  '3'),
             ---
             ('j', '10'),
             ('k', '11')
    ) AS ref (check_col, result_column) 
    ON ref.check_col = t.column ;
```

Answer (score -4):

one way to get around this is to include the test in the `when` clause i.e.

```
case
  when SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1) = 'a' THEN '1'
...
```

Comment: Actually no. Both `SELECT CASE v.V WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 END FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b')) AS v (V);` and `SELECT CASE WHEN v.V = 'a' THEN 1 WHEN v.V = 'b' THEN 2 END FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b')) AS v (V);` translate to *exactly the same* execution plan (feel free to verify that for yourself), where the CASE expression is redefined as `CASE WHEN [Union1002]='a' THEN (1) ELSE CASE WHEN [Union1002]='b' THEN (2) ELSE NULL END END` – with nesting, as you can see.